# How to get number of merged pull requests by author via console?

Tags: git, git-log

I'm trying to get statistic how many pull requests were merged by author.

For example I have repository `https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign`.
On contribution page I see that I  merged 6 pull requests.
But I want to get this statistic via console (for some reason I can't get this statistic via UI).

I use following command: `git shortlog --summary --numbered --all` but it returns 20 commits for me.

Is there any additional parameter that can be used to get correct statistic?

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to get?

The problem is that you commited with 2 different **names**:

- Sergei Korneev 23792@mail.ru
- gromspys 23792@mail.ru

[image]

[image]

Here you can see that you have 5 commits in the master branch.

### [image]

[image]

Comment: I expect to see 6, not 5

Comment: I don't see my commit "Java 11 HTTP client incorrectly reports 'invalid URI' exception message when cause is thread interruption (#2191)" that I can see here https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/commits?author=gromspys

Comment: Thank you @codewizard. I saw 20 commits locally and after reinstalling repository I see 5 commits for Sergei Korneev and 1 for gromspys. Is there any way to group it by email? Another question: in my example all PRs were squashed, but what if somebody just merged PR without squash? For example I have 1 PR with 2 commits and squashed my PR and another contributor has 10 commits and  merged without  squash. Statistic will show 1 commit for me and 10 for another contributor. Is there a way to count merged PRs? it was the main my question.

Comment: I will try to answer your question tomorrow, If the you got answer please be kind enough to vote for the answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I will wait your answer. Just I have some repositories that didn't have any restriction for squashing and I'm trying to get statistic how many PRs were merged by team member.